# Advice on the use of :exe "norm!" vs. built in functions when writing vimscipt and plugins

Tags: vimscript, plugin, execute

I've been using vim for about 3 years and am starting to write [my first
plugin](https://github.com/Matt-A-Bennett/surround-funk.vim). I've noticed when
looking at the code of other popular plugins that the functions very rarely
seem to achieve their aim with lines like:

```
execute "normal! <some commands>"
```

Instead opting to use Vim's built in functions. Given the power of Vim's
normal mode commands to do so much, what is the general reason for not
employing them more often when writing plugins? For example is there a good
reason to prefer code (A) or (B) (given that they achieve the same result):

Code (A):

```
let l = line(".")
let c = col(".")

call search('mysearch')
call setline(line("."), 'better')

call cursor(l, c)
```

Code (B):

```
normal! mx

execute "normal! /mysearch/\<CR>"
normal! 0c$better

normal! `x
```

Code (A) seems a little more readable, and won't clobber the marks (and not the
search registers?). Is there a more important reason I'm missing?

Comment: I'm with you on the readability (though, being opinion-based, that's not the basis for any answer, of course :) and have my own preference (builtins over `norm` all the way) but I never stopped to think about what, if any, practical (and fact-based) difference there might be. I wonder if there's any appreciable performance difference in any functionally equivalent cases.

Comment: This seems likely to be not a good fit here. But: personally, if I can do it without clobbering marks, I use Ex and Normal mode commands where possible and go towards functions otherwise. Plugins should try their best to not clobber registers, marks, search patterns, settings, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In no particular order.

1. **Readability** Any sequence of normals, except a very short one, is nearly impossible to read and understand. Vimgolf can't lie.
2. **Clobbering registers etc.** Quite often there is more things to change than one can even remember of. For example, your code sets at least four(!) registers and six(!) marks. Plus `:h changelist` and `:h jumplist`. Sometimes it's good, but usually scripts need to preserve stuff.
3. **Error handling** Normals could fail in the middle of a sequence. Also, how do you know if "mysearch" was even found or not?
4. **Behaviour change** Many normals work differently depending on user-settable options such as `&virtualedit`, `&selection`, `&whichwrap`, `&wrap`, `&iskeyword` and so on. Again, sometimes it's good, but usually it's a pain.

Comment: I like the error handling point +1.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but I think you'll appreciate it.

```
let saved_pos = getcurpos()
call search('mysearch')
normal! 0c$better
call setpos('.', saved_pos)
```

I used "better" functions ("better" - maybe not. Up to you). And mixed/matched normals with scripts. What do you think?

---

Read this: **Master Wq and the Markdown acolyte** from https://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/vim-koans/ :)

Scripts beat normal commands in terms of composability. Scripts work with data instead of strings. It's like bash commands vs. powershell commands (if you have experience with that). Or it's like understanding and transforming MEANING vs. characters. That's more univeral, but unfortunately more abstract.

So... if you're building something small, `normals` are great! And if you're building something large, scripts are great!

Comment: Thanks for the answer (+1) - I'm in the process of translating the functions in my plugin from using `normal` commands to using the built-ins. Holding data and states in variables allows a lot more precision and flexibility and allows me to make progress a lot faster.

Comment: At that point, perhaps `:normal! ccbetter`.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I did have `ccbetter` in my original example - but I think `cc` matches the existing indent of the line, unlike `setline()`. That in itself may be another good argument in favour of using built-ins...